# Workarounds for using ClojureScript with the OpenJDK?

Tags: clojure, heroku, java, clojurescript

I've been working on a project with Clojure and Noir and I'm enjoying the free hosting on Heroku's cedar stack.  I've recently added some UI work in ClojureScript to find that it works locally but crashes on Heroku due to their use of the OpenJDK.  The OpenJDK has the Rhino JavaScript engine in a different namespace.

Has anyone heard of a workaround to this problem?  Can a version of Rhino with the correct namespace be installed as a project dependency?  Or is there an alternative to Heroku that uses the Oracle JDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/e99856b836d99e3d), the issues with ClojureScript and OpenJDK are supposed to have been resolved on the ClojureScript [master branch](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a feature request for the ClojureScript bug-tracker. Lots of people have this issue (at least I do) so it should get attention.

Heroku is not really intending to support ClojureScript (yet) and does a lot more in terms of hosting than a compiled ClojureScript program really needs. perhaps you can find a provider that will just host javascript and send them the compiled.js instead of a java class that starts it's own java interpreter.

I agree that not using Heroku is a pain because it has the best (of my experiences) integration with git+clojure+leiningen. perhaps either Heroku or the Clojure folks will fix this soon :-/